# Drawerlayout slide content instead of menu

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I made an app using the library: [jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu). But this library is a little bit old and I want to use Appcompat library.

So my question is **if it is possible to use the drawerLayout for sliding the content away and making the menu fixed?** istead of the normal drawerLayout implementation, where the Menu slides in front of the content view.

Like in the facebook app:

[image]

Comment: Somebody is voting me down with every question I ask. For no reason. Say why plz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brother for that you need to create your own library just like Jeremy Feinstein who created SlidingMenu library ,google'android uses the concept of navigation drawer (https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) which is similar to the one created by Jeremy. Creating a drawer layout with the menu fixed is a tough concept and is not available on the internet due to facebook copyright issues; So I am really sorry to say you have to be satisfied with the SlidingMenu library you presently have.

Comment: And if I want to write my own library where can I start? Because I really want to use appcompat.

Comment: Even I was trying to get the drawer layout which facebook uses, I worked 11 days on it but ultimately did'nt get it.Later I came to know that it was designed by a pro and it had copyright issues.Creating library is a very tough thing , it requires creation of multiple classes with functions which are supposed to be accessed by the child class for example we extend Activity class in most programs , it is a part of the ADT library.So if you want to start from the ground level you need to create classes with functions that can be used by the child class.

Comment: Ow ok because I want the concept to be the same buth the layout is going to be totally different so I don't think I am going to have issues with copyright.

Comment: If you copy paste the whole code then only you will have copyright issues other wise u won't.